# Use HTML Tidy to just indent HTML code?

Tags: html, htmltidy

Is it possible to use HTML Tidy to just indent HTML code?

**Sample Code**

```
<form action="?" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">

<ul>
<li>
<label class="screenReader" for="q">Keywords</label><input type="text" name="q" value="" id="q" />
</li>
<li><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search" /></li>
</ul>


</form>
```

**Desired Result**

```
<form action="?" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <label class="screenReader" for="q">Keywords</label><input type="text" name="q" value="" id="q"/>
        </li>
        <li><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

If I run it with the standard command, `tidy -f errs.txt -m index.html` then I get this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Mac OS X (vers 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 15.3.6), see www.w3.org">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="?" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<ul>
<li><label class="screenReader" for=
"q">Keywords</label><input type="text" name="q" value="" id=
"q"></li>
<li><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search"></li>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**How can I omit all the extra stuff and actually get it to indent the code?**

Forgive me if that's not a feature that it's supposed to support, what library / tool am I looking for?

Comment: Other folks have suggested that http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&html might be a better option if you *just* want to indent.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the  `indent`, `tidy-mark`, and `quiet` options:

```
tidy \
  -indent \
  --indent-spaces 2 \
  -quiet \
  --tidy-mark no \
  index.html
```

Or, using a config file rather than command-line options:

```
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 2
quiet: yes
tidy-mark: no
```

Name it `tidy_config.txt` and save it the same directory as the .html file. Run it like this:

```
tidy -config tidy_config.txt index.html
```

For more customization, use the [tidy man page](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html) to find other relevant options such as `markup: no` or `force-output: yes`.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It is still adding a meta generator tag.  Is there a way to turn off *all* changes except indentation?

Comment: Use the [tidy man page](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html) to reference and test the flags. Try turning off defaults by adding `markup: no` or `input-xml: yes` and `force-output: yes` to the config file.

Comment: If you are a fan of oneliners without intermediate files, you can write the same as `tidy -xml --indent auto --indent-spaces 2 --quiet yes index.html`.

Comment: `tidy-mark: no` should turn off the meta generator tag,

Comment: @DaveBurton Good catch. Thanks!

Comment: Leave out `input-xml: yes` (`-xml`) since it will flag `<input>` as an error.

Comment: If anybody's having issues passing options from command-line, make sure you're not separating the value from the option with an equals-sign (`--option=value`). It requires a space to be used (that was where I was going wrong - thanks @tlwhitec!)

Comment: This is still adding missing tags - such as `<title>` to my (php) document. I can't find anything in the man page for strict indent only without adding tags. I am hoping to format included documents - title tags are included from another file.

Comment: Looks like the magic option needed to omit the `DOCTYPE`, `html`, `head`, and `title` tags is `--show-body-only yes`. It's a shame this is hard to find in the docs. The words "title" and "snippet" do not appear, however the docs do mention "fragment" when describing the `--show-body-only` option. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 25):

I didn't found a possibility "only reindent - without any changes". The next config file will "repair" as low as possible and (mostly) only re-indent the html. `Tidy` still correcting some errorish conditions, like duplicated (repeated) attributes.

```
#based on http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html
#HTML, XHTML, XML Options Reference
anchor-as-name: no  #?
doctype: omit
drop-empty-paras: no
fix-backslash: no
fix-bad-comments: no
fix-uri:no
hide-endtags: yes   #?
#input-xml: yes     #?
join-styles: no
literal-attributes: yes
lower-literals: no
merge-divs: no
merge-spans: no
output-html: yes
preserve-entities: yes
quote-ampersand: no
quote-nbsp: no
show-body-only: auto

#Diagnostics Options Reference
show-errors: 0
show-warnings: 0

#Pretty Print Options Reference
break-before-br: yes
indent: yes
indent-attributes: no   #default
indent-spaces: 4
tab-size: 4
wrap: 132
wrap-asp: no
wrap-jste: no
wrap-php: no
wrap-sections: no

#Character Encoding Options Reference
char-encoding: utf8

#Miscellaneous Options Reference
force-output: yes
quiet: yes
tidy-mark: no
```

For example the next html-fragment

```
<div>
<div>
<p>
not closed para
<h1>
h1 head
</h1>
<ul>
<li>not closed li
<li>closed li</li>
</ul>
some text
</div>
</div>
```

will changed to

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>
            not closed para
        <h1>
            h1 head
        </h1>
        <ul>
            <li>not closed li
            <li>closed li
            </ul>some text
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can notice, the `hide-endtags: yes` hides the closing `</li>` from the second bullet in the input. Setting the `hide-endtags: no` - will get the next:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>
            not closed para
        </p>
        <h1>
            h1 head
        </h1>
        <ul>
            <li>not closed li
            </li>
            <li>closed li
            </li>
        </ul>some text
    </div>
</div>
```

so, `tidy` adds closing `</p>` and closing `</li>` to first bullet.

I didn't found a possibility preserve everything on input and only reindent the file.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Used this in my PHP script and the html output looks great.  Took me a while to copy the attributes so here's a pastebin for anyone looking to config tidy like this: https://pastebin.com/JP8ucTzc

Comment: hide-endtags: NO

Comment: Thx for this explanation. But how to turn "</ul>some text" into "</ul>\nsometext"?  And how to keep the empty lines in the source code?

Answer (score 18):

You need the following option:

```
tidy --show-body-only yes -i 4 -w 80 -m file.html
```

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#show-body-only

`-i 4` - indents 4 spaces (*EDIT*: <strike>tidy never uses tabs</strike>)
or
`--indent-with-tabs yes` - instead (`--tab-size` may affect wrapping)

`-w 80` - wrap at column 80 (default on my system: 68, very narrow)

`-m` - modify file inplace

(you may want to leave out the last option, and examine the output first)

Showing only body, will naturally leave out the `tidy-mark` (generator `meta`).

Another cool options are:
`--quiet yes` - doesn't print W3C advertisements and other unnecessary output
(errors still reported)

Comment: The "show-body-only: yes" is the correct answer (even if partial - tidy can't not fix broken tags).

Comment: Tidy does use tabs, just add `--indent-with-tabs yes` to command line arguments.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the poster's original question, using Tidy to *just indent* HTML code, here's what I use:

`tidy --indent auto --quiet yes --show-body-only auto --show-errors 0 --wrap 0 input.html`

**input.html**

```
<form action="?" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">

<ul>
<li>
<label class="screenReader" for="q">Keywords</label><input type="text" name="q" value="" id="q" />
</li>
<li><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search" /></li>
</ul>


</form>
```

**Output:**

```
<form action="?" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <ul>
    <li><label class="screenReader" for="q">Keywords</label><input type="text" name="q" value="" id="q"></li>
    <li><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search"></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

No extra HTML code added. Errors are suppressed. To find out what each option does, it's best to refer to the [official reference](http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/tidylib_api_5.1.25/quick_ref.html).

Comment: In vim:
`%!tidy --show-errors 0 --show-body-only auto -qi -w 0`

Comment: Unfortunately these options are not enough. tidy inserts a form tag around this code:
`<input id="a" type="checkbox"><label for="a">a</label>`
But this one is fine:
`<label><input id="a" type="checkbox">a</label>`

`tidy --version` outputs `HTML Tidy for Linux released on 25 March 2009`

Answer (score 2):

I am very late to the party :)

But in your tidy config file set

tidy-mark: no

by default this is set to yes.

Once done, tidy will not add meta generator tag to your html.

Comment: My version of `tidy` (and probably any other) will accept configuration options also as command line options (which is sometimes more desirable than dragging around a config file), like: `tidy --tidy-mark no -utf8 -w 80 -i file.html`.

Comment: This does not prevent the generation of `DOCTYPE`, `html`, and `head` tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to simply format whatever html you receive, ignore errors and indent the code nicely this is a good one liner using `tidy`

```
tidy --show-body-only yes -i 4 -w 80 -m -quiet --force-output y -wrap 0 2>/dev/null
```

You can use it with `curl` too

```
curl -s someUrl | tidy --show-body-only yes -i 4 -w 80 -m -quiet --force-output y -wrap 0 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Where does the input file go in the first command?

Comment: The second command starts with `curl -s someUrl |` and that `|` is a redirect to the rest of the command. So, you could curl some website and redirect it, or you could say `cat index.html | tidy --show-body-only yes -i 4 -w 80 -m -quiet --force-output y -wrap 0 2>/dev/null` for instance

Answer (score 0):

None of the html tidy based solutions worked for me - all of them modified the content to some extent, so I create a CLI tool and Go package https://github.com/a-h/htmlformat based off https://github.com/ericchiang/pup

It uses the Go `net/html` package to parse the HTML, and a custom writer to write out the content with indentation.