# Is there a github action or workflow to format html files or a way to do it programmatically that is fail safe?

Tags: html, python-3.x, formatting, github-actions

I generate HTML file programmatically. As imagined its quite ugly but works perfectly.
I was wondering if there is a *github action* or a *workflow* that I can write that will convert the file into a pretty looking html file.

Writing a *workflow* that uses Python is fine too. However I must point out that **BeautifulSoup fails to correctly indent my file**(output misses some tags - perhaps because the generated html is untidy due to line breaks etc) - moreover it uses a single space indenting system, I need **4 spaces**.

Some other tools I looked into -

- html5print - Isn't maintained it seems - idle since 5 years
- HTML Tidy - Doesn't seem to work with Python 3.X

Don't know if I will be able to run the following in a workflow file via actions -

- [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)
- [brackets-beautify](https://github.com/brackets-beautify/brackets-beautify)
- [web-beautify](https://github.com/yasuyk/web-beautify)

I haven't explored other languages, but I am open to them, especially `Go` and `Ruby`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install `tidy` via `apt` and just run it directly in CI pipeline. So, assuming that you have some python script that generates `page.html` for you. Here is the configuration that runs `tidy` with generated file:

#### page.html ("generated" file)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src="bundle.js"></script><title>My Page</title></head><body><div id="app"><p>Paragraph 1</p></div></body></html>
```

#### .github/workflows/test.yml

```yaml
---
name: Test

on: push

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      # here is some step that generates HTML file with python
      - run: sudo apt install tidy
      - run: tidy page.html > page2.html
      - name: Print generated page
        run: cat page2.html
```

#### Result

[image]

`tidy` is pretty much customizable, so you can configure it for your needs. Just run `man tidy` or follow [official documentation](http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/) to see possible options.

Comment: I understand that its supposed to work, but when I run it on my rendered HTML, it just left aligns everything. No indentation, nothing whatsoever. In the head, it also places things in 2 lines instead of one. I don't think it works well.

Comment: Did you play with `tidy` options? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937448/470214) solution works for me perfectly, shows formatted HTML with indentation - [Print generated page](https://github.com/fabasoad/business-card/runs/674156604).

Comment: Looks like you are onto something. Please give me sometime. Bogged down with a few things here. Will check and let you know soon.

Comment: `tidy --indent auto --indent-spaces 2 --tidy-mark no --force-output yes -o index_output.html index.html` seems to work for me now.