# Vim, Twig and html indentation

Tags: php, html, symfony, vim, twig

I'm trying to format html in Twig files, but I'm facing issues with the indentation. I've explored various solutions:

**Prettier (via ALE plugin):** Unfortunately, it doesn't support Twig.

**Running `php bin/console lint:twig templates/`:** This approach doesn't seem to work.

**twig-lint:** Unfortunately, it's outdated.

**Adding `let g:twig_indent_html = 1` and `autocmd FileType twig setlocal ft=twig syntax=twig autoindent` in .vimrc:** This didn't yield the desired results.

**Twig-CS-Fixer**

**prettier-plugin-twig-melody (and its fork : https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/@supersoniks/prettier-plugin-twig-melody)**

I've also tried https://github.com/nelsyeung/twig.vim, https://github.com/lumiliet/vim-twig and https://github.com/qbbr/vim-twig

Additionally, I experimented with using htmlhint via CocInstall coc-htmlhint, along with the configuration:

```
let g:coc_filetype_map = {
\ 'twig': 'html',
\ }
```

A short sample :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Welcome - Home{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div>
<p>Hello!</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

A short sample I want :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Welcome - Home{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div>
    <p>Hello!</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

However, I'm still encountering issues with Twig file indentation. Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you post a [mre] including a short sample file, the indentation you expect and the actual result. The way your question is written, all anybody could do is to suggest some tool and hope it fulfills your secret requirements.

Comment: Okay, I don't have any particular style requirements, having indentation is already cool at this stage, but I'll give an example.

Answer (score 2):

With tidy, an external commande, it's possible :
`:<line-to-start>,<line-to-end>!tidy --show-errors 0 --show-body-only auto -qi -w 0`

You can specify the lines as follows: `:5,46!tidy --show-errors 0 --show-body-only auto -qi -w 0` for an application from line 5 to 46.
Answer found here:
[Use HTML Tidy to just indent HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151180/use-html-tidy-to-just-indent-html-code)

In .vimrc, you can add this for format on save :

```
augroup AutoTidy
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost *.html,*.twig execute 'silent! %!tidy --show-errors 0 --show-body-only auto -qi -w 0 --indent-spaces 4'
augroup END
```